# Laravel Package: How to register a third party facade inside a custom package?

Tags: laravel, laravel-facade, laravel-package

I'm creating a package that uses internally this [hashid package](https://github.com/vinkla/laravel-hashids).

**How can I register a third party facade inside a custom package?**

I tried three options and none of them worked.

1. Version - Composer

   ```
   "aliases": {
        "Hashids": "Vinkla\\Hashids\\Facades\\Hashids"
   }
   ```
2. Version - inside my ServiceProvider with alias

   ```
    class MyPackageServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
    {
       public function register()
       {
           ...

           $this->app->alias(\Vinkla\Hashids\Facades\Hashids::class, 'Hashids');
       }
   ```
3. Version - inside my ServiceProvider with AliasLoader

   ```
    class MyPackageServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
    {

       public function register()
       {
           ...

           $loader = \Illuminate\Foundation\AliasLoader::getInstance();
           $loader->alias('Hashids', \Vinkla\Hashids\Facades\Hashids::class);
        }
   ```

---

When I'm testing the code, I get the error:

```
Error: Call to undefined method Vinkla\Hashids\Facades\Hashids::encode()
```

inside

```
/** @test */
public something_to_test()
{
    dd(\Hashids::encode(1));
}
```

Comment: what about inside composer.json of custom package ?

Comment: @JohnLobo that's what you see in my "version 1". I put the alias line inside my composer.json of the custom package not of the parent Laravel app

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found one solution, but I am still confused why it is like that.

In my "MyPackageServiceProvider" I need to add:

```
$this->app->register(HashidsServiceProvider::class);
```

Why do I need to register a Provider? I thought the composer is handling the work.

At the end only this works:

```
$this->app->register(HashidsServiceProvider::class);
$loader = \Illuminate\Foundation\AliasLoader::getInstance();
$loader->alias('Hashids', \Vinkla\Hashids\Facades\Hashids::class);
```

The other versions doesn't work as well :(